# phpmyadmin is not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, server, phpmyadmin

I am stuck with ubuntu 14.04 unable to work with phpmyadmin, showing some weird code.. 
Followings are the versions of my php, MySQL, and server I installed in.

PHP 7.2.9-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2018 07:44:26) ( NTS )
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
/// mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.61-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

I've tried everything to figure this problem but still failed.
I installed libapache2-mod-php7.2, and php-mcrypt, php-gettext, and did a2enconf php7.2-fpm. It all didn't work. 
Also, I tried to add "#Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf" in apache2.cnf but then I got an error about alias problem when I restart the server.

This is the sample of code I got from  www.my_serverIP/phpmyadmin

```
addJSON('list',RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('recent')->getHtmlList());exit; } if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) {if (isset($_REQUEST['git_revision']) && $GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] == true) {PMA_printGitRevision();exit;}echo '
```

Could anybody please help with this problem?

Comment: `showing some weird code` - can you add to your question what that weird code is, as it could be a useful error message, or otherwise highlight the cause

Comment: see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/800810/phpmyadmin-shows-weird-code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800810/phpmyadmin-shows-weird-code)